# Add custom form value to price

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, price

I've created a form within my custom module that displays on the product page that calculates a price, based on the input how would I add this to the product price?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create observer for this

First create **events.xml** file in folder

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend and use event ‘**checkout_cart_product_add_after**’.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create CustomPrice.php file in Observer folder.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        $price = $observer->getEvent()->getData('price_field'); //Your price field

        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```